# Store value session using ViewModel for login in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-2.0

I'm using UserViewModel for rendering views(both login view and registration view). I've one property called user_id which I'm using as primary key in my User Table.

My UserViewModel.cs:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int    user_id         { get; set; } //Primary Key in user table

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Email:")]
    public string email           { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name:")]
    public string f_name          { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name:")]
    public string l_name          { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Contact Number:")]
    public string contact         { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Gender:")]
    public string gender          { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Blood Type:")]
    public string blood_type      { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Password:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password        { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("password")]
    public string confirm_password { get; set; }
}
```

My Login Action Method:

```
public ActionResult Login(UserViewModel uvml)
{
    
    var login = db.users.Where(a => a.email.Equals(uvml.email) && a.password.Equals(uvml.password)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (login != null)
    {        
        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "User");
    }
        
    return View();
}
```

How can I store the value of user_id in session?

Answer (score 0):

You can access `Session` directly from your action method:

```
if (login != null)
{        
  Session["user_id"] = login.user_id;  
  return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "User");
}
```

`Session` stores everything as an `object` so you have to cast it when retrieving it. ex:

```
int user_id = (int) Session["user_id"];
```

You can use it to retrieve the user in another action method:

```
if(Session["user_id"] != null)
{
    int user_id = (int) Session["user_id"];
    UserViewModel user = db.users.Where(a => a.user_id == user_id).FirstOrDefault();    
}
```

Comment: can i use it in other classes via:
int user_id = (int) Session["user_id"]; ??
Suppose I want to use the session variable  in any other ViewModel for other purposes such as querying database?